# How to use Textbox without using textbox name when I pass the textbox as parameter in WinForms C# 2010

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a function which take TextBox as parameter. I am using this function under Textbox change event.

```
    private void ZeroDigit(TextBox txt)
    {
        string Prefix = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < txt.MaxLength; i++)
            Prefix += "0";
        txt.Text = (txt.Text.Trim() == "" ? "" : string.Format("{0:" + Prefix.Trim() + "}", System.Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text.Trim())));
    }


    private void txtCCID_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ZeroDigit(txtCCID);
    }
```

Problem is I have to write every time every textbox name when using this function. 
Here I wrote ZeroDigit(txtCCID), If I want to use 10 TextBox I have to write 10 times 10 different TextBox name.

Is there any way that without writing Textbox name it will take the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a single handler and bind all your text boxes to the it. Then pass the sender object to your function.

```
private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ZeroDigit(sender as TextBox);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have,

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ZeroDigit(sender as TextBox);
}
```

Now Attach this event to all TextBox

```
txtCCID.TextChanged +=TextBox_TextChanged;
```

Or you can use this in from load

```
 foreach(Control Ctl in this.Controls)
   {
if(Ctl is TextBox)
(Ctl as TextBox).TextChanged +=TextBox_TextChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the same event handler to each TextBox's TextChanged event. Like this:

```
txtCCID.TextChanged += txtCCID_TextChanged;
txtAnotherTextBox.TextChanged += txtCCID_TextChanged;
```

and so on...

Then use `sender` parameter to decide which textbox raised this event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create unificated handler as others suppose to you.
If you create your gui by code with no graphic designer used, you might consider creating own class `MyHandledTextBox`, derive from `TextBox` class and the only change to it would be in the constructor, meaing every `MyHandleTextBox` instance is automatically assigned to the handler. If you would be using this handler extensively, perhaps in more views, this could save up some time and a lot of boiler-plate code.